# Copy text from one AcroField to another

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrofields

I'm trying to copy text from an AcroField named "Date Signed" to the field "In_Person_Date" if a checkbox is ticked. I tried

```
function sync()
{
  var n1 = document.getElementById('Date Signed');
  var n2 = document.getElementById('In_Person_Date');
  Date Signed.value = In_Person_Date.value;
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="Date Signed" id="Date Signed" onkeyup="sync()">
<input type="text" name="In_Person_Date" id="In_Person_Date"/>
```

Which I got from another answer, but it didn't work.

Comment: In which environment should this be done?

Comment: I'm using Foxit PhantomPDF. I am adding a script that executes when I click the checkbox.

Comment: Have you looked at the Foxit documentation for scripting? The above is web browser JavaScript, not Acrobat JavaScript.